# How to use column value as parameter for mysql function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

Can anyone help me with this sql statement?

```
SELECT c.id AS 'cat_id', c.name, sol.id,
   (SELECT f.id
   FROM folders f, category_folder_mapping cf
   WHERE cf.folder_id = f.id AND cf.category_id = c.id
   ORDER BY f.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS 'folder_id'
FROM categories c
OUTER APPLY folderFirstSolution(folder_id) sol
ORDER by c.id ASC
```

My goal in this sql is to use the 'folder_id' as parameter for the folderFirstSolution() function. I always get an sql syntax error.
Please tell me what's wrong with this statement. 
Thanks ahead.

(EDIT)
MYSQL ERROR:
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER APPLY folderFirstSolution(folder_id) sol
ORDER by c.id ASC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7

Comment: try removing single quotes(') from AS  'folder_id'

Comment: MySQL does not support `outer apply` (or lateral joins as this is called in standard SQL)

Comment: I've edited the post, that's the error that mysql gives. I've tried removing the single quotes to but the same error.

Comment: so that's why it's not working. I found that when searching, i thought it works. So what can you suggest to make this query possible? is there a way to use a column for a function parameter?